# OneClassSVM scikit learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have two data sets, trainig and test. They have labels "1" and "0". I need to evaluate these data sets using "oneClassSVM" Algorithm with "rbf" kernel in scikit learn. I loaded training data set, but I have no idea how to evaluate that with test data set. Below is my code,

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np

input_file_data = "/home/anuradha/TrainData.csv"
dataset = np.loadtxt(input_file_iris, delimiter=",")

X = dataset[:,0:4]
y = dataset[:,4]

estimator= svm.OneClassSVM(nu=0.1, kernel="rbf", gamma=0.1)
```

Please some one can help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as adding the following two lines of code at the end of your script:

```
estimator.fit(X_train)
y_pred_test = estimator.predict(X_test)
```

The first line tells svn which training data to use and the second one makes prediction on the test set (be sure to load both datasets and to change variable names accordingly).

[Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_oneclass.html) there is a complete example on how to use `OneClassSVM` and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.OneClassSVM.html) the class reference.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Is it possible to set labels with training and test data set? How?

Comment: @Prabhath with OneClassSVM you don't need labels because there is only one class. Take a look at this [link](http://rvlasveld.github.io/blog/2013/07/12/introduction-to-one-class-support-vector-machines/) for more details. If you want more classes you could consider to use ```svm.SVC``` or some of its variants (see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.svm)).